# How can I get token from the URL in Nextjs / React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on an API based project.

I have my front-end interface with React and Next.js and the API back-end builds with Laravel.

I have a front-end page with a token in URL which I have made in my Laravel back-end to identify the user.

**Question:**

How can I get the token from URL in client-side for sending it back to my back-end in a post request to compare and verify the user then insert it in my database?

Comment: how does your url(with a token) look like?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera http://localhost:3000/add-account/e37d145cbbbcd3ce833e421d2ee622ef2d2963bbd5ac8e8c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve it using props, (ignore `this.` if you use a function component as `YourPage`)

```
this.props.match.params.token
```

You also need to have a route definition like this

```
<Route exact path="/add-account/:token" component={YourPage}/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the response with next.js.

Build a dynamic route for the name file like this [token].js

Then use destructuring and hooks useRouter like this :

`const router = useRouter();`

`const { token } = router.query;`